# Why is there an indent on first line of tabbing environment

Tags: indentation, tabbing

I'm trying to use tabbing environment at title page of a `scrartcl` to format content. Unfortunately there seems to be some indent on first row of my text (giving minimal example) I'm not sure where it comes from. It looks like this: [image: Indent on tabbing]

This is the LaTeX code I was using:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{tabbing}
Erstellt für: \hspace{0.5em} \= Max Mustermann \kill{}
Erstellt für: \> Max Mustermann  \\
Datum \> \today \\
\end{tabbing}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

and now I'm wondering, what did I wrong or what can I improve to don't have the Indent on `Erstellt für`

Comment: Maybe it's the usual indent? Have you tried putting `\noindent` before that? And why does the MWE state `Erstellt für` twice, while it only renders once in the image?

Comment: @Ronny no, it isn't.

Comment: @Ronny -- if you don't understand david's comment, the reason "Erstellt für" only renders once is because the last command in the first line is `\kill`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification David, i saw the kill after your comment; anyways thanks for the explanation barbara.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `{}` after `\kill` which is making the end of line make a space.

Comment: Right when you wrote your answer, I found it myself ;). Still not 100% understanding what's happening there to be honest.

Comment: @frlan white space after command  names is ignored but not after `}` compare  `zzzz \LaTeX zzz` and  `zzzz \LaTeX{} zzz`